# A countable inductive first-order theory which has non existentially-closed (e.c) model has a non e.c. model of any inifinite size

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

I'm trying to prove Lindström's theorem, which says that a countable inductive first order theory $T$ which is $\kappa$-categorical for some $\kappa\geq \aleph_{0}$ is model-complete.

The strategy I follow is proving each model has an existentially-closed extension of any bigger cardinality, which I proved using transfinite induction. Now, I try to prove an analogous result for non-e.c models - if $T$ has non-e.c. model, then it has a such a model of any infinite size. Using downwards Löwenheim-skolem, we can assume that $M\models T$ is a countable model which is not e.c.

So there is another model $N$ which thinks a certain existential sentence with parameters in $M$ that $M$ does not think. I tried to elementarily extend both $M$ and $N$ in a manner that preserves the inclusion in each step, but it doesn't seem to work.

Once I know this two facts, we obtain 2 models of cardinality $\kappa$ - one of which is e.c. and the other is not, contradicting the fact they are isomorphic. I'd like to know how to fill in this specific part.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the two-sorted structure $(M, N)$ with constants representing elements in $M$ and an added function representing the inclusion map $M \to N$. Let $T$ be the theory of this structure. Add $\kappa$ many constants of the first sort to the language and add axioms stating these constants take distinct values. By compactness, we conclude that this new theory admits a model $(M’, N’)$. Clearly $|M’| \geq \kappa$. Using downward Löwenheim-Skolem if necessary, we may assume $M’$ and $N’$ are both of cardinality exactly $\kappa$. Clearly $M’$ elementarily extend $M$ and $N’ \supset M’$. $N’$ is also elementarily equivalent to $N$ with parameters in $M$. Thus, these structures satisfy the properties you want.

Comment: I'm not familiar with multiple-sorted structures, can this be proven without such reasoning?

Comment: @Oria You can always pretend it’s a single-sorted structure by taking the disjoint union and add a predicate indicating which sort the element is. I’m unable to come up with a proof that avoids this kind of reasoning altogether at the moment though.

Comment: I see! The part I missed was using a predicate to distinguish between elements of $M$ and elements of $N$. I'll try to formalize it, thank you!

Comment: I started writing down a first-order theory, but I seem to get stuck - Say I take the elementary diagram of $N$, and add the sentences $\left\{ c_{i}\neq c_{j}\;\vert\;i\neq j<\lambda\right\} \cup\left\{ P\left(c_{i}\right)\;\vert\;i<\lambda\right\}$  where all the $c$'s are new constants.  How can I force $P$ to realize an elementary extension of $M$ inside of the new model?

Comment: @Oria Add the axioms saying all elements of $M$ satisfy $P$ and none of the elements of $N \setminus M$ satisfies $P$. Then for any sentence $\varphi$ with parameters from $M$, clearly in the original structure $\varphi^P$ is true iff $\varphi$ is true in $M$, where $\varphi^P$ replaces all quantifiers in $\varphi$ by quantifiers that only range over elements satisfying $P$. (Since in the original structure satisfying $P$ and being in $M$ are equivalent.)

Comment: @Oria Then in the extended structure, $\varphi^P$ must also be true iff $\varphi$ is true in $M$. Of course, this just means all elements satisfying $P$ form a structure that’s an elementary extension of $M$. (You need to verify that elements satisfying $P$ is closed under all the functions, but that can be done by just adding axioms insisting that be the case.)

Comment: Just to make sure - formally, is it that $\varphi^{P}=\psi\left(\overline{x}\right)\land\bigwedge_{x_{i}\in\overline{x}}P\left(x_{i}\right)$? Where $Q_{1}\cdots Q_{n}\overline{x}\psi\left(\overline{x}\right)$ is $\varphi$ in prenex form.

Comment: @Oria If $Q = \exists$ then yes, I meant changing $\exists x \varphi(x)$ to $\exists x (\varphi(x) \wedge P(x))$. If $Q = \forall$ then what I meant is changing $\forall x \varphi(x)$ to $\forall x (P(x) \to \varphi(x))$.

Comment: @Oria This is just bounded quantifiers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantifier)

Comment: Oh, I see! I feel like my experience with such construction is lacking, any recommendations for books containing model theory arguements of this kind?

Comment: @Oria Sorry, I don’t know any good book on these topics either. Model theory is not my area of expertise. I mainly just learned these in a scattershot way when working on related problems.